# .NET Core IOT (No Data coming from Seed Studio Grove DTH11 Sensor when using without Grove Shield)

Tags: .net, .net-core, raspberry-pi, iot, gpio

I am using Grove DTH11 Sensor to connect to raspberry pi 4 and get the reading from the sensor using .NET Core IOT and GPIO Pins. I am connecting the sensor directly to the Pi without using Grove Pi+ or Grove Shield.

The problem is I am not getting any reading from the sensor. Below is the code i am using

```
int pin = 4;
using (GpioController controller = new GpioController()) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Opening Pin - " + pin);
    controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Input);
    Console.WriteLine("Pin - " + pin + " opened successfully");
 
    using (Dht11 dth11Obj = new Dht11(pin, PinNumberingScheme.Logical)) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Dht11 object created");
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("reading data"); 
            var temp = dth11Obj.Temperature; 
            var hum = dth11Obj.Humidity; 
            Console.WriteLine("data read successfully"); 

            if (dth11Obj.IsLastReadSuccessful) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Temperature: {temp.DegreesCelsius}\u00B0C, Relative humidity: {hum.Percent}%"); 
                Console.WriteLine($"Heat index: {WeatherHelper.CalculateHeatIndex(temp, hum).DegreesCelsius:0.#}\u00B0C"); 
                Console.WriteLine($"Dew point: {WeatherHelper.CalculateDewPoint(temp, hum).DegreesCelsius:0.#}\u00B0C"); 
             } 
             else 
             { 
                 Console.WriteLine("Error reading DHT sensor"); 
             }
             
             Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The output of the above code is below.

```
Opening Pin - 4
Pin - 4 opened successfully
Dht11 object created
reading data
```

The execution gets stuck after displaying "reading data" and no sensor readings are coming.

The connection of Raspberry Pi and Sensor is as below -

```
Pin GND of Dth11 Sensor is Connected to Pin 6 of Raspberry Pi 4
Pin VCC of Dth11 Sensor is Connected to Pin 1 of Raspberry Pi 4
Pin NC  of Dth11 Sensor is Connected to Nothing
Pin SIG of Dth11 Sensor is Connected to Pin 7 (GPIO 4) of Raspberry Pi 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not open the pin before.
Remove line `controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Input);`
See: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/c8130309c99a35ce68a10c40ca9003b0261cc2ef/src/devices/Dhtxx/DhtBase.cs#L100

Comment: i tried using it without opening the pin, but no luck. This error is related to Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Pin 4 does not support mode InputPullUp.
at System.Device.Gpio.GpioController.SetPinMode(Int32 pinNumber, PinMode mode). Github Issue - https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/1291

Comment: You should try the latest 1.3 version that should fix the issue. You may have bumped into 2 different cumulative issues:
- InputPullUp not supported on RPI4
- Problem of board detection on some RPI4